# While loop exiting instead of returning back to the top of the loop -Python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am having problems at the end of the while loop. When completing the game the program asks you if you want to play the game again after you input yes it set the player variable to false so you can continue the loop, but if you input anything the program exit.

```
# Importing Random
from random import *

win = 0
lose = 0
draw = 0

print("[y/Y] Play game")
print("[n/N] Quit")

answer = input("Do you wanna play a game?: ")

if answer == "y" or answer == "Y":
    # Show score of game
    print("Score:", win,"wins,", draw, "draws,", lose,"losses")

    #create a list of play options
    plays = ["ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS"]

    #assign a random play to the computer
    computer = choice(plays)

    #set player to False
    player = False

    while player == False:
        #set player to True
        player = input("Choose one: rock, paper or scissors: ").upper()
        if player == computer:
            print("Draw, try again")
            # Add 1 to the draw score
            draw += 1

        elif player == "ROCK":
            if computer == "Paper":
                print("You lose!", computer, "covers", player)
                # Add 1 to the lose score
                lose += 1

            else:
                print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer)
                # Add 1 to the win score
                win += 1

        elif player == "PAPER":
            if computer == "Scissors":
                print("You lose!", computer, "cut", player)
                # Add 1 to the lose score
                lose += 1

            else:
                print("You win!", player, "covers", computer)
                # Add 1 to the win score
                win += 1

        elif player == "SCISSORS":
            if computer == "Rock":
                print("You lose...", computer, "smashes", player)
                # Add 1 to the lose score
                lose += 1

            else:
                print("You win!", player, "cut", computer)
                # Add 1 to the win score
                win += 1

        else:
            print("That's not a valid play. Check your spelling!")

        # Ask the player for a new game
        new_game = input("Do you wanna play again?: ")

        if answer == ["Y", "y", "Yes", "yes", "YES"]:
            # Set player to false again to continue loop
            player = False
            computer = choice(plays)

        elif answer == ["N", "n", "no", "No", "NO"]:
            global flag
            flag = 1
            exit()
    if flag == 1:
        exit()

elif answer == "n" or answer == "N":
    exit()
```

The problem is with this part
 # Ask the player for a new game
            new_game = input("Do you wanna play again?: ")

```
        if answer == ["Y", "y", "Yes", "yes", "YES"]:
            # Set player to false again to continue loop
            player = False
            computer = choice(plays)

        elif answer == ["N", "n", "no", "No", "NO"]:
            global flag
            flag = 1
            exit()
    if flag == 1:
        exit()

elif answer == "n" or answer == "N":
    exit()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if answer in ["Y", "y", "Yes", "yes", "YES"]` (with `in` rather than `==`) ?

Comment: @khelwood's answer will partially fix your problem, but you should also use `elif answer in ["N", "n", "no", "No", "NO"]` for the same reason.

Comment: ok, I did that and now works, but the new problem is the opposite. anything I input leads back to the top

Comment: Solved, I had to change the variable new_game with answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to change the variable new_game with answer